# How to get a stacktrace with deprecated method calls?

Tags: php, symfony, debugging, stack-trace, deprecated

### The problem

I'm using Symfony 2.7.1

In the Symfony's profiler, I can easily see how many deprecated method calls I have.

[image]

When I click on the profiler, I get details:

[image]

I know that Symfony can manage stacktraces in the profiler, but I don't know where to configure it.

---

### The ugly solution

I manually edited <kbd>Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler</kbd> class and changed:

```
// line 401
if ($type & $level) {
```

By:

```
// line 401
if (true) {
```

I now can see stacktraces for every line:

[image]

### My question

By looking at the [source code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2aeaa22e3171b5e1f10f2cc2a7ff7f6608b65f9d/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/ErrorHandler.php), I am afraid that all the configuration is taken from the private members of the class.

Is there a more beautiful way to get deprecated stacktraces on the profiler?

Comment: [This document](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/profiler/profiling_data.html) seems to suggest that there's a profiler service that you can use from the command line to export profile data, but I am using 2.7 on an instance here and the command isn't available to me. Still, might be worth a look

Comment: Yes strange, commands exist in `Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\Command` but it seems that they are not loaded. Looks not to be an environment issue, tried to enforce `dev` but nothing.

Comment: Bizarre! Consider me intrigued :)

Comment: The reason: http://symfony.com/blog/cve-2014-6072-csrf-vulnerability-in-the-web-profiler

Comment: By the way, the blog post also contains a typo, the right import is: `- { resource: @WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/commands.xml }`.

Comment: Did you find a nice way to configure this without having to change the vendor code?

Comment: Hello, yes, this bug was fixed 5 days ago: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/15647 We just need to wait for the next release.